# Would this TV stand made almost entirely of 3/4 in birch plywood withstand the load?

Tags: plywood, weight-capacity

I'm currently doing a TV stand, pretty new to woodworking. And I was wondering if this would be able to hold the weight of the TV + soundbar? Let's say 40 kg / 88 pounds. The TV base is about 99 cm/39.3 inches wide 25 cm/9.9 inches depth.
The TV stand is made using 3/4 inches birch plywood.

This is a rough sketch of it.
[image: Sketch look from the front]

So basically 2 meters wide, 56 cm tall (+ legs). Supported by 5 walls: edges, middle, and 2 walls 40 cm away from the center. (As seen in the picture). The walls are 3/4 thick.

Basically:

Edge wall - - 60 cm - - Wall - - 40 cm - - Center wall - - 40 cm - - Wall - - 60 cm - - Edge wall.

Edge wall - - 23.625 in - - Wall - - 15.75 in - - Center wall - - 15.75 in - - Wall - - 23.625 in - - Edge wall.

Everything, except the legs is 3/4 in birch plywood.

The legs are just mostly for looks. They are wood planks, 8.8 cm/3.46 wide, about 2 inches tall. They are going to be distributed like this.
[image: Sketch look from below]

And at the top we are also using some screws to secure the walls in place (and glue). 5 screws by wall, separated by 10 cm/ 3.94 in along the "wall"
[image: Sketch look from above]

I have been wondering if this is going to withstand the load...  I'm going to use some bricks to test the load once the tv stand is done and wait a week or two, just to be safe. But what do you think?

Comment: Hi, from sketch I think this would take 200kg no problem!

Comment: 3/4" (18mm) plywood is _very_ strong. You won't have a problem.

Comment: You could probably build this out of 1/2" plywood to save money and still not have to worry about supporting the weight of a TV and soundbar.

Comment: Also, no need to wait "a week or two". Once the glue dries (1-2 hours, depending on temp & humidity), it's good to move around. Full cure should be within 24 hours. (All assuming standard carpenter's PVA-type glue). An extra week after that won't make a lick of difference.

Comment: At 88 pounds, that must be a massive flat panel TV. I have a 65" 4k that's 44 lbs. Or the speaker must weigh around half that 88 lbs.

Comment: In WW2, the US built ocean going PT boats out of 3/4 " plywood. Very successful, too!

Comment: IKEA would sell you the same thing made with 3/8" MDF.  Yours will hold up a tank.

Comment: Thanks all of you, that is very reassuring. Just started working with wood so I was worried. @computercarguy the TV is 71.9 lbs with the stand it comes with, the soundbar about 7.1 lbs. I just added a few more pounds for other things that may be placed on top.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you build this right I think you could safely park a motorcycle on top of it. And no, I'm not exaggerating. A (very large apparently!) TV and soundbar should not pose any risk whatsoever.

As already mentioned in the Comments 3/4" / 18mm birch ply is strong, assuming it is decent quality very very strong. And glue-and-screws construction is also a strong and reliable way of putting together plywood projects. So you're lining yourself up for success already.

In addition, in case you're not aware, the back can add a very significant strength component to cabinetry. By fixing firmly to a back panel (even a relatively thin one) you effectively lock the entire shape which prevents racking, barring the fasteners snapping, tearing free or ripping out chunks of plywood.

Comment: Or a B-52. [ATLAS-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATLAS-I) 'designed to test the radiation hardening of strategic aircraft systems against EMP pulses from nuclear warfare. The world's largest structure composed entirely of wood and glue laminate.'

Answer (score 8):

3/4" plywood is VERY strong.  I have some on a shelf in my shed holding my turning wood, I used full 4'x8' sheets and I have several hundred pounds on it.  no dipping.  I also have some 1/2" plywood on 32" wide shelves and it does a pretty good job.

So yes.  A top only 19" wide with even less support than you are planning would have no problems with a an 88 lbs TV.  It should look pretty nice when you are done.